# How to configure nginx with chef solo on vagrant?

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, vagrant

I have a vagrant VM that boots ok and I have provisioned it with nginx through:

```
config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
chef.add_recipe "nginx"
```

and when it boots, nginx is installed and running. Perfect. (I use berkshelf to manage the cookbooks, that one comes from opscode)
Now I want to actually configure nginx, in this case to run as a reverse proxy. I can't seem to find how. I could have a conf file ready and send it to the VM but I'm sure there is another way to take advantage of the cookbook. The best option would be to be able to configure it directly from within the Vagrant file along the lines described above. Maybe using something like custom json data as described here http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html.
It would look something like:

```
chef.json = {
    "nginx" => {
```

But the cookbook page at http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/nginx is a bit cryptic to me, there are interesting options but I don't know how to include / use them.

Comment: Have you seen the docs on GitHub: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx

Comment: The formatting in the Chef community website is not particularly good for reading the cookbooks' readmes. Try in the [GitHub page](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Indeed it is easier to read, but I have yet to understand the format that goes into the Vagrantfile. Any docs or example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure nginx as a reverse proxy, then you'll need to write a cookbook recipe that calls either a `cookbook_file` resource or a `template` resource. I'd recommend going with the latter as it'll be more flexible later on and will provide you with a reusable template for other recipes to use.

I'd recommend you read the docs here:
http://docs.opscode.com/resource_template.html#using-templates

and if you want to see a reverse proxy example from a real cookbook. Take a look here:

https://github.com/lusis/chef-kibana/blob/master/recipes/nginx.rb

https://github.com/lusis/chef-kibana/blob/master/templates/default/kibana-nginx.conf.erb

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "opscode-ubuntu-14.04"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://opscode-vm-bento.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/virtualbox/opscode_ubuntu-14.04_chef-provisionerless.box"

    config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo 'set nocp' > /home/vagrant/.vimrc"

    config.vm.define "nginx" do |nginx|

        nginx.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.14"

        nginx.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
            chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
            chef.add_recipe "nginx"

            chef.json = {
                :nginx => {
                    dir: '/etc/nginx'  # this is the default value, sample only
                }
            }
        end

        nginx.vm.provision "shell",
            inline: "echo -e $1 > /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf",
            args: [<<-EOS
                server {
                    listen *:80;

                    location ~ ^/ {
                        proxy_pass http://192.168.33.11:8080;
                    }
                }
            EOS
            ]

    end
```

Note that where I write nginx.config, I could write other per-site configs (domain1.conf, domain2.conf) and they will all be loaded.

I ended up needing to pull quite a few cookbooks down:

```
https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx
    https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/build-essential
    https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ohai
    https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/bluepill       
        https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/rsyslog
    https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/runit
    ??
        https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/yum
```

Comment: Note that I still need a vagrant reload to get the nginx.conf configuration to reload.